Inference with Onnx gives error: Required inputs are missing from input feed
I'm trying to test my ONNX model by running an inference. I built a Keras sequential model, and trained it on the Iris data set, and then converted it to ONNX. I don't think I have my input, signature correct. I have 4 columns as my input and the examples I find online show a single tensorSpec with a single name. I used the examples I found, and I got this error:
ValueError: Required inputs (['x']) are missing from input feed (['sepal length (cm)', 'sepal width (cm)', 'petal length (cm)', 'petal width (cm)'])

I tried changing the input signature to the code below, but that still didn't work.
input_signature = 
[tf.TensorSpec(model.inputs[0].shape, model.inputs[0].dtype, name="sepal length (cm)"),
tf.TensorSpec(model.inputs[0].shape, model.inputs[0].dtype, name="sepal width (cm)"),
tf.TensorSpec(model.inputs[0].shape, model.inputs[0].dtype, name="petal length (cm)"),
tf.TensorSpec(model.inputs[0].shape, model.inputs[0].dtype, name="petal width (cm)")]

I dont understand how to set the input signature up correctly for a Keras Sequential model. Here's the full script. The problem is in the last 13 lines of code where the model is saved and then loaded as an onnx model.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import onnxruntime as rt
import tf2onnx
import onnx

plt.style.use('ggplot')

from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler

iris = load_iris()
X = iris['data']
y = iris['target']
names = iris['target_names']
feature_names = iris['feature_names']

# One hot encoding
enc = OneHotEncoder()
Y = enc.fit_transform(y[:, np.newaxis]).toarray()

# Scale data to have mean 0 and variance 1
# which is importance for convergence of the neural network
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X)

# Split the data set into training and testing
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(
    X_scaled, Y, test_size=0.5, random_state=2)

n_features = X.shape[1]
n_classes = Y.shape[1]

# Visualize the data sets
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 6))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
for target, target_name in enumerate(names):
    X_plot = X[y == target]
    plt.plot(X_plot[:, 0], X_plot[:, 1], linestyle='none', marker='o', label=target_name)
plt.xlabel(feature_names[0])
plt.ylabel(feature_names[1])
plt.axis('equal')
plt.legend();

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
for target, target_name in enumerate(names):
    X_plot = X[y == target]
    plt.plot(X_plot[:, 2], X_plot[:, 3], linestyle='none', marker='o', label=target_name)
plt.xlabel(feature_names[2])
plt.ylabel(feature_names[3])
plt.axis('equal')
plt.legend();

# In order to ignore FutureWarning
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=DeprecationWarning)

import tensorflow as tf

def create_custom_model(input_dim, output_dim, nodes, n=1, name='model'):
    def create_model():
        # Create model
        model = tf.keras.Sequential(name=name)
        for i in range(n):
            model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(nodes, input_dim=input_dim, activation='relu'))
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(output_dim, activation='softmax'))

        # Compile model
        model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                      optimizer='adam',
                      metrics=['accuracy'])
        return model
    return create_model

models = [create_custom_model(n_features, n_classes, 8, i, 'model_{}'.format(i))
          for i in range(1, 4)]

for create_model in models:
    create_model().summary()

history_dict = {}

# TensorBoard Callback
cb = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard()

for create_model in models:
    model = create_model()
    print('Model name:', model.name)
    history_callback = model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
                                 batch_size=5,
                                 epochs=50,
                                 verbose=0,
                                 validation_data=(X_test, Y_test),
                                 callbacks=[cb])
    score = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=0)
    print('Test loss:', score[0])
    print('Test accuracy:', score[1])

    history_dict[model.name] = [history_callback, model]

create_model = create_custom_model(n_features, n_classes, 8, 3)

model = history_dict["model_3"][1] #model 3 was the most accurate
model.save("Iris.keras")
input_signature = [tf.TensorSpec(model.inputs[0].shape, model.inputs[0].dtype, name="x")]
model.output_names=['output']
onnx_model, _ = tf2onnx.convert.from_keras(model, input_signature, opset=13)
onnx.save(onnx_model, "Irismodel.onnx")

sess = rt.InferenceSession("Irismodel.onnx")
input_name = sess.get_inputs()[0].name
label_name = sess.get_outputs()[0].name
dataset = pd.DataFrame({"sepal length (cm)" : X_test[:,0],"sepal width (cm)": X_test[:,1],
                        "petal length (cm)": X_test[:,2], "petal width (cm)": X_test[:,3]})

pred = sess.run([label_name], dataset)


If I get the input signature correct, then I am expecting to get a list of predictions in the last line of code.
